# Sumar 2 columnas de un array si el valor no es nulo

Tags: php, laravel, array

Tengo el siguiente array:

[image: array]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver las columnas de tallas, (t1,t2,t3...) pueden ser tanto string como int. Y lo que quiero es que en esas columnas si el valor no es nulo, y no es texto ( si es texto ya me encargo de hacer la conversión), sumarle la otra columna "merma" a todas las tallas.

Antes de utilizarlo en la vista estoy tratando de hacer esto con este fragmento de codigo:

```
 $materiales_tallax = $compo_escandallo->where('xtalla','=','X');

 foreach($materiales_notallax as $arrayline){
     foreach($arrayline as $campo => $valor){
         if(strpos($campo, 't') === 0){
             if ( $campo != ""){
                 //array_sum();
                // Aqui quiero realizar la suma del valor de la columna t1,t2,t3... + la columna merma y devolver el mismo array con la suma realizada.
                 intval($valor) + $arrayline->merma;
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Pero al intentar hacer la suma, aparte de darme errores porque estoy trabajando con "collections" o "stdClass", array_sum tampoco me sirve porque hasta donde vi y se no suma solo una columna, y la verdad ya no se me ocurre como podría hacerlo.

Muchas gracias anticipado.

Comment: Eso valores que tu indicas como INT, por ejemplo, `0,225`, no lo son. En todo caso serian float, pero ni eso, porque usan una coma en lugar de un punto para separar los decimales. Tampoco se entiende que quieres hacer aquí: `intval($valor) + $arrayline->merma;`  pues no lo asignas a nada.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario @masterguru, puse en la pregunta que podía ser texto, en cuyo caso ya haría la conversión pertinente para hacer la suma. 
Aclarando tu otra pregunta, y ahora edito el post,  no quiero asignar ese valor a ninguna otra variable quiero sobrescribir el valor de las columnas t1,t2,t3.... con la suma del valor que tiene dicha columna mas la otra columna "merma". Y devolver el mismo array si es posible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que lo que faltaba era guardar el valor de la suma, en la posición que querias.

Si tienes problemas al asignar el valor, puedes hacer un `->toArray()` antes para estar seguro que trabajas solo con arrays puros y no Collections.

```
$materiales_tallax = $compo_escandallo->where('xtalla','=','X');
    
foreach($materiales_notallax as $index => $arrayline){
    foreach($arrayline as $campo => $valor){
        if(strpos($campo, 't') === 0){
            if ( $campo != ""){
                // Sobreescribimos el valor original
                $materiales_notallax[$index][$campo] = intval($valor) + $arrayline->merma;
                // En el caso que la posición sea un objeto, lo podemos hacer así:
                $materiales_tallax[$index]->$campo = $val;
introducir el código aquí
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Otro problema, será luego que intval() devuelva el valor que tu quieres, pues tal y como decían `0,35` devolverá 0 y no 0.35

Comment: Me ha servido a la perfección, he creado una función para convertir cualquier string numérico a float, y cabe mencionar que aunque convertí el std::Class a array como me dijiste con ->toArray(), las diferentes colecciones dentro del array no se convierten a array y para poder acceder al objeto que deseo sobrescribir he tenido que ponerlo así = $materiales_tallax[$index]->$campo = $val; ( lo dejo por si alguien mas le ocurre o si quieres editar la respuesta incluso). Lo dicho, un saludo y muchas gracias.